# Previous page redirect in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to create a php code that writes a file and then goes back to the previous page.
This is my code:

```
<?php
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    $file = 'data.txt';
    $current = file_get_contents($file);
    $current++;
    file_put_contents($file, $current);
    header("location:javascript://history.go(-1)");
    exit;
?>
```

When I run it in Google Chrome it works perfectly. But in internet explorer it says:

> This page can’t be displayed

Any ideas what to do? I've tried changing many stuff, using another javascript methods to go to the previous page, and php and none of them worked..

P.S. the script does run even when I open it in internet explorer, but when it gets to the redirect part it just displays the error and doesn't redirect.

**Live Example:**

send.php: http://klh-dev.com/send.php

data.txt: http://klh-dev.com/data.txt

Comment: That cannot run perfectly because you `exit` before doing anything with the file!!

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry wrong file version.. I edited look now, thanks!

Comment: That does not work. I am pretty sure you cannot pass a javascript command to the browser in a header command

Comment: @RiggsFolly It works in google chrome, and the counter actually worked in both browsers.. In google chrome everything works perfectly, in internet explorer the script works just it doesn't redirect and displays an error (even though it displays an error the script does run)

Comment: If you look at the Chrome debugger you will see this generates an error

Comment: FYI same error fired with Firefox!

Comment: Can't you use the SERVER referrer or something?